# Python : Is there a Way to Rotate and Reposition a rectangle in 2D?

Tags: python, rotation, rotational-matrices

Hey Guys I am searching for a possible solution for this:

I have Points which build a rectangle.

Now I am trying to transform it:

- **Rotation r for x-Degress (lets say 30 degrees clockwise)
  this is the hardest for me**
- Move in X and Y Direction (lets say 1 to the X and 10) ((already solved, but maybe more elegant way?)
- scale it by 2 (already solved, but maybe more elegant?)

Im thinking about it quite long but, can't figure it out myself (still super beginner though)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#arrays for Points
x = [2,8,8,2,2]
y = [1,1,4,4,1]
plt.plot(x,y)

# scale specific Points by 2 
x_scaled = x
y_scaled = y
x_scaled[1] = x[1]*2
x_scaled[2] = x[2]*2
y_scaled[2] = y[2]*2
y_scaled[3] = y[3]*2 

#move rectangle by x = 1 and y by 10
x_pos = [x+1 for x in x_scaled]
y_pos = [x+10 for x in y_scaled]

plt.plot(x_scaled,y_scaled)
plt.plot(x_pos, y_pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a function like this:

```py
def rotate(x_list, y_list, angle):
    angle = math.radians(angle)
    new_x = []
    new_y = []
    centre_x = sum(x_list)/len(x_list)
    centre_y = sum(y_list)/len(y_list)
    print(centre_x, centre_y)
    for i in range(len(x_list)):
        x = centre_x + math.cos(angle)*(x_list[i] - centre_x) - math.sin(angle)*(y_list[i] - centre_y)
        y = centre_y + math.sin(angle)*(x_list[i] - centre_x) + math.cos(angle)*(y_list[i] - centre_y)
        new_x.append(x)
        new_y.append(y)
    return new_x, new_y
```

It's a bit primitive and verbose but seems to work fine from what I've tested. It does also require you import the math module.

Comment: coming close to what im looking for, thank you very much!.

Only thing im concerned about, that I believe we now rotated from the center and not over Point 1. 

I think since the Values of the bottom left Point appears 2 times in the Lists it effects the calculation, so that it its not an rectangle anymore and more like a 
parallelogram. 

Do you have any Idea how to fix that ?:) 

Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Each point is calculated separately so it doesn't matter if they are duplicated in the list as the duplicates will still resolve to the same new point. As for rotating around a point, you can set the centre to wherever you want but I just took the average position of all points, which as you correctly pointed out is only the centre of the shape if the lists have no duplicated points, but you can deal with this however you choose.